# TS2339: Property 'Cell' does not exist on type from @type/react-table in typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics, react-table-v7, react-table-v6

I use the `@type/react-table` to set up the column for my table and I have error on my IDE complain that `Cell` is not under correct type. I assume it is caused by `Cell` is optional type from `@type/react-table` how can I solve this?

```
//column.tsx
import {Column, Cell} from 'react-table';

export interface ColumnValue {
    [key: string]: any;
}
export type TableColumn = Column<ColumnValue>
export function createColumn(colDef: TableColumn): TableColumn {
  return colDef;
}
export const name = createColumn({
  id: 'name',
  Header: 'Name Column',
  Cell({value}}) {
    return value.hyperlink
  },
});


//column.test.tsx
import {render} from '@testing-library/react';
import {name} from './Name';

describe('Test Name Column', () => {

  it('shows the name', () => {
    const {getByText} = render(
      name.Cell({
      // Error show TS2339: Property 'Cell' does not exist on type 'TableColumn'
        value: {hyperlink: 'asadasd'}}),
      })
    );
    expect(getByText('i am name')).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

Comment: Looking  at the type defintion for react-table, I don't see `Cell` on `Column` type, so the error makes sense: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/react-table/index.d.ts#L69

Comment: the `Cell` is under `ColumnInterfaceBasedOnValue` that is union of `ColumnWithStrictAccessor` and union of `Column ` https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/react-table/index.d.ts#L61-L63. however it is optional though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition of `Column` is a union of a bunch of different types describing possible column configurations.  Only some of them have a `Cell` property.  `ColumnGroup` does not.  Therefore you don't know for sure that a variable of type `Column` supports the `Cell` property.

You can get around this by making your `createColumn` function generic.  It enforces that `colDef` is assignable to `TableColumn` but doesn't widen the type.

```
export function createColumn<C extends TableColumn>(colDef: C): C {
  return colDef;
}
```

Now you get an error further down the chain because `Cell` expects to be called with the complete `CellProps`.

---

Update:

The current setup infers the type of the props for a valid `Cell` in your column configuration as `CellProps<ColumnValue, any>`.  This means that you can just write `Cell({value}) {` without specifying the props type.

You cannot make use of the inferred props type for `Cell` of *and also* get typescript to infer that your particular `Cell` only uses the prop `value` from those (at least not without some advanced Typescript trickery).

It's easy to declare that the `Cell` only needs a value prop, but you have to state that explicitly.

```
export const name = createColumn({
  id: 'name',
  Header: 'Name Column',
  Cell({value}: {value: ColumnValue}) {
    return value.hyperlink
  },
});
```

---

The `render` method of React Testing Library expects to be called with a `ReactElement`.  Right now your `Cell` returns `any` due to the loose definition of `ColumnValue {[key: string]: any;}`.  But probably `value.hyperlink` is a `string` which would be a Typescript error.  You should wrap it in a fragment, either in the `Cell` itself or in the `render`.

```
export const name = createColumn({
  id: 'name',
  Header: 'Name Column',
  Cell({value}: {value: {hyperlink: string}}) {
    return value.hyperlink
  },
});
```

The above definition will cause an error in the test so you need to do this:

```
const { getByText } = render(
  <>
    {name.Cell({
      value: { hyperlink: "asadasd" }
    })}
  </>
);
```

Comment: I got the error `TS2345: Argument of type '{ value: any; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'PropsWithChildren<CellProps< ColumnValue, any>>'.   Type '{ value: any; }' is missing the following properties from type 'TableInstance< ColumnValue>': state, plugins, dispatch, columns, and 70 more.` after i change to your suggestion

Comment: Yeah that’s what I meant by “Now you get an error further down the chain because Cell expects to be called with the complete CellProps.”

Comment: I see. any solution for it?

Comment: thank you. but any other way for me to declare the type for `value` in `Cell` the code from question is just a simple example. however, in my really application. it is way from complicated